# Button toggle div visible property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application that requires not an actual logging to the DB, but a verification of data before accessing the menu. I am using a `<div>` to display an error message of a failed validation. The validation takes place in the code behind. I want the event to be able to change the div's visibility property to be hidden or visible, but it fails as the page gets reloaded and therefore it appears that no change has been made.

In a nutshell:

```
<div runat="server" id="Errmsg" style="visibility:false">
</div>
<div id="otherDiv">
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="IdDepTxt"></asp:TextBox>(just as an example)
   <asp:Button ID="AccessBtn"  runat="server" OnClick="AcessBtn_Click" Text="ACCESS"  CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
private boolean validate_data(string Parm1)
{
    //some code that connects to a db and looks for Parm1 in a table
}

protected void AccessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validate_data(IdDepTxt.text))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Menu.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Errmsg.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the `visible` property in the markup, instead of `visibility`: `<div runat="server" id="Errmsg" visible="false">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `false` is not a valid value for the [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) property. You are probably looking for `hidden`.

```
style="visibility: hidden;"
```

The valid values are as follows:

> visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;

Secondly, you are mixing ASP.NET and CSS visibility functionality. You should choose one or the other instead of both. Otherwise they will conflict with each other and you may not see what you expect to see.

CSS:

```
<div runat="server" id="Errmsg" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

```
Errmsg.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
```

ASP.NET:

```
<div runat="server" id="Errmsg" Visible="False">
```

```
Errmsg.Visible = false;
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Panels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of divs. They act as containers just as divs do, but are a little easier to work with in your code behind when it comes to ASP.NET functionality.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Errmsg" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Just as a feedback I had that mistake of considering those functionalities as equivalent. Now that I chosen a side (star wars pun?), it works perfect, thanks a lot. (Chose the server side by the way and the visibility=false was a type-o I had the correct style applied at css level :D)

Comment: And that's totally understandable. Luckily, it's something that is quite easy to test! You're welcome. Glad I could help!